# Best practice for Swift methods that can return or error

Tags: swift

I’m practicing Swift and have a scenario (and a method) where the result could either be successful or a failure.

It’s a security service class. I have a method where I can authenticate with an email address and password, and want to either return a `User` instance if the credentials are correct, or throw some form of `false` value.

I’m a bit confused as my understanding of Swift methods is you need to specify a return type, so I have:

```swift
class SecurityService {
    static func loginWith(email: String, password: String) -> User {
        // Body
    }
}
```

I’ve seen in Go and Node.js methods that return a “double” value where the first represents any errors, and the second is the “success” response. I also know that Swift doesn’t have things like errors or exceptions (but that may have changed since as I was learning an early version of Swift).

What would be the appropriate thing to do in this scenario?

Comment: *I also know that Swift doesn’t have things like errors...*. It does have errors! Since Swift 2 there is a very powerful advanced error handling.

Comment: Swift does support error handling, see the [Error Handling section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html) of the Swift Programming Language guide.

Comment: @vadian And I did qualify that sentence with _but that may have changed since as I was learning an early version of Swift_, which seems to be the case.

Comment: @MartinBean Swift evolves very quickly. Try to get always tutorials and documentation of the most recent version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an answer to this question (five years later), there’s a dedicated `Result` type for this exact scenario. It can return the type you want on success, or type an error on failure.

It does mean re-factoring some code to instead accept a completion handler, and then enumerating over the result in that callback:

```swift
class SecurityService {
    static func loginWith(email: String, password: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<User, SecurityError>) -> Void) {
        // Body
    }
}
```

Then in a handler:

```swift
securityService.loginWith(email: email, password: password) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let user):
        // Do something with user
        print("Authenticated as \(user.name)")
    case .failure(let error):
        // Do something with error
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

If you want to handle errors that can happen during login process than use the power of Swift error handling:

```
struct User {
}

enum SecurityError: Error {
    case emptyEmail
    case emptyPassword
}

class SecurityService {
    static func loginWith(email: String, password: String) throws -> User {
        if email.isEmpty {
            throw SecurityError.emptyEmail
        }
        if password.isEmpty {
            throw SecurityError.emptyPassword
        }
        return User()
    }    
}

do {
    let user = try SecurityService.loginWith1(email: "", password: "")
} catch SecurityError.emptyEmail {
    // email is empty
} catch SecurityError.emptyPassword {
    // password is empty
} catch {
    print("\(error)")
}
```

Or convert to optional:

```
guard let user = try? SecurityService.loginWith(email: "", password: "") else {
    // error during login, handle and return
    return
}

// successful login, do something with `user`
```

If you just want to get `User` or `nil`:

```
class SecurityService {    
    static func loginWith(email: String, password: String) -> User? {
        if !email.isEmpty && !password.isEmpty {
            return User()
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

if let user = SecurityService.loginWith(email: "", password: "") {
    // do something with user
} else {
    // error
}

// or

guard let user = SecurityService.loginWith(email: "", password: "") else {
    // error
    return
}

// do something with user
```

Comment: I know swift has error handling (try, throw, etc.) but I think using optionals and nil checks is so much cleaner

Comment: @DougMead: Optional returns are fine when you don't care about *why* or *how* something failed. The error handling system is for when you need to communicate that kind of info.

Answer (score 4):

Besides the standard way to `throw` errors you can use also an `enum` with associated types as return type

```
struct User {}

enum LoginResult {
  case success(User)
  case failure(String)
}

class SecurityService {
  static func loginWith(email: String, password: String) -> LoginResult {
    if email.isEmpty { return .failure("Email is empty") }
    if password.isEmpty { return .failure("Password is empty") }
    return .success(User())
  }
}
```

And call it:

```
let result = SecurityService.loginWith("Foo", password: "Bar")
switch result {
  case .Success(let user) : 
     print(user) 
     // do something with the user
  case .Failure(let errormessage) : 
     print(errormessage) 
    // handle the error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Returning a result enum with associated values, throwing exception, and using a callback with optional error and optional user, although valid make an assumption of **login failure** being an **error**. However thats not necessarily always the case.

- Returning an enum with cases for success and failure containing result and error respectively is almost identical as returning an optional `User?`. More like writing a custom optional enum, both end up cluttering the caller. In addition, it only works if the *login* process is synchronous.
- Returning result through a callBack, looks better as it allows for the operation to be async. But there is still error handling right in front of callers face.
- Throwing is generally preferred than returning an error as long as the scope of the caller is the right place to handle the error, or at least the caller has access to an object/method that can handle this error.

Here is an alternative:

```
func login(with login: Login, failure: ((LoginError) -> ())?, success: (User) -> ()?) {
    if successful {
        success?(user)
    } else {
        failure?(customError)
    }
}

// Rename with exactly how this handles the error if you'd have more handlers, 
// Document the existence of this handler, so caller can pass it along if they wish to.
func handleLoginError(_ error: LoginError) {
    // Error handling
}
```

Now caller can; simply decide to ignore the error or pass a handler function/closure.

```
login(with: Login("email", "password"), failure: nil) { user in 
    // Ignores the error 
}

login(with: Login("email", "password"), failure: handleLoginError) { user in 
    // Lets the error be handled by the "default" handler.
}
```

PS, Its a good idea to create a data structure for related fields; `Login` email and password, rather individually setting the properties.

```
struct Login {
    typealias Email = String 
    typealias Password = String 

    let email: Email
    let password: Password
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What’s the advantage of putting the email and password in a struct, rather than as method arguments?

Comment: I'd say its cleaner, more readable, and easy to refactor. It makes changing the types easier, you can also easily make this `Codable` to convert to json if needed. You can also extend the data structure to add functions like `validate` for example. Or imagine you suddenly want to support some social media login like facebook. You can easily change `Login` to be an enum with multiple login methods and initializer for each, one of which would be `init(email: Email, password: Password)` which will return the emal-password login case. Keeps things flexible :)

Comment: Logging in with various providers, could I not define multiple `loginWith()` methods with different parameter signatures, i.e. `loginWith(mfaToken: String)`, `loginWith(facebookAccessToken: String)` etc?

Comment: Yes. The data-structure approach simply abstracts "logging in" maybe be a bit better in my opinion. I cannot think of a better example but here is one: lets say you wanna implement caching for current login, you can define your `Cachable` protocol, whatever that might be, `Login` can conform to it providing how each case could be cached, and your `Cacher` will just cache without bothering/knowing about login internals. When you start supporting a new login method lets say `Twitter` login, your changes will be limited to only on the `Login` data-structure `Cachable`, hence better abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the result of calling **loginWith** could be derived from a network request, here is code that I could do in the scenario you presented:

Helper classes:

```
struct User {
  var name: String
  var email: String
}

class HTTP {
  static func request(URL: String, method: String, params: [String: AnyObject], callback: (error: NSError?, result: [String:AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Void {
    // network request
  }
}
```

---

```
class SecurityService {
  static func loginWith(email: String, password: String, callback: (error: NSError?, user: User?) -> Void) -> Void {

    let URL = ".."
    let params = [
      "email": email,
      "password": password
    ]

    HTTP.request(URL, method: "POST", params: params) { (error, result) in
      if let error = error {
        callback(error: error, user: nil)
      } else {
        guard let JSON = result else {
          let someDomain = "some_domain"
          let someCode = 100
          let someInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "No results were sent by the server."]

          let error = NSError(domain: someDomain, code: someCode, userInfo: someInfo)
          callback(error: error, user: nil)
          return
        }

        guard let name = JSON["name"] as? String, email = JSON["email"] as? String else {
          let someDomain = "some_domain"
          let someCode = 100
          let someInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "No user properties were sent by the server."]

          let error = NSError(domain: someDomain, code: someCode, userInfo: someInfo)
          callback(error: error, user: nil)
          return
        }

        let user = User(name: name, email: email)
        callback(error: nil, user: user)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Using the **SecurityService** class:

```
SecurityService.loginWith("someone@email.com", password: "123456") { (error, user) in
  if let error = error {
    print(error)
  } else {

    guard let user = user else {
      print("no user found.")
      return
    }

    print(user)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is _exactly_ what I was wanting!

Comment: What about Throwing errors or Result type?
Do write in Swift or some other language?
Please read about error handling in swift
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html