# How to correctly show nested JSON image in SwiftUI without breaking the old swift theme?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to show the image next to the disclosure view which is the cover of the book. The images comes from the struct , which is used to call the json nested data to show in disclosure group along with the images. The JSON files are locally saved which are called to show it in disclosuregroup.

**What i tried and getting issue::**

1. Used the Async image to show it in 'Hstack' but compiler not letting
   me run the code.
2. Used List instead of Foreach to manage container,
   but it breaks the theme with hexcolor code.

The Code used to achieve the above image::

```js
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ContentView: View {

  @EnvironmentObject var booksList: BooksList
  @State var books: [BookModel] = []
  @State var selection: BookModel?

  var body: some View {

    //        NavigationView {

    VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 40) {

      ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {

          ForEach(booksList.books){ book in

          //Alternative way , each book on seperate view
          //NavigationLink(destination: lvl4(books: [book], selection: nil)){
          //                                               Text(book.bukTitle!)
          //

          if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
              
              if #available(iOS 15, *){
              label: do {
                  AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "\(book.coverImage!)")) .scaledToFit()  .fixedSize(horizontal:true, vertical: true) .frame(minWidth: 10, maxWidth: 20)
              }
              }
              
              DisclosureGroup( "\(Text(book.bukTitle!) .fontWeight(.medium) .font(.system(size: 30)))"
            ) {
                 
              ForEach(book.bookContent ?? []) { bookContent in
                  
                DisclosureGroup(
                    "\(Text(bookContent.title).fontWeight(.medium) .font(.system(size: 25)))"
                ) {
                  OutlineGroup(bookContent.child, children: \.child) { item in
                      
                     

                    NavigationLink {

                      if #available(iOS 15, *) {
                        ScrollView {
                          Text(attributedString(from: item.title, font: Font.system(size: 25)))
                            .padding(30).lineSpacing(10).navigationTitle(Text(bookContent.title))
                            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)

                        }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                          .background(Color(UIColor.hexStringToUIColor(hexStr: ("efe8d2"))))
                      }

                    } label: {
                      if #available(iOS 15, *) {
                        Text(
                          "\(Text(attributedString(from: item.title, font: Font.system(size: 23) )))"
                        )
                        .lineLimit(1).lineSpacing(20)
                      } else {
                        // Fallback on earlier versions
                      }
                    }
                    .disabled(item.child != nil).lineSpacing(20)
                  }.lineSpacing(20)
                }.lineSpacing(20)
              }
              }
          }
             }.lineSpacing(20)
      }.lineSpacing(20)
    }.padding(35).lineSpacing(20)

  }
```

The following code is used  Booklist:

```js
import Foundation

class BooksList: ObservableObject {
    @Published var books:[BookModel]
    init() {
        let booksManager = VBBooksManager()
        books = booksManager.loadAllSavedBooks() ?? []
    }
}
```

The following code is used for BookModel.

```js
import Foundation

enum BookParseError: Error {
    case bookParsingFailed
}

struct BookModelForJSONConversion: Codable {
    var id:Int
    var title: String?
    var content: [BookContent]?
    var bookCoverImage:String?
    
    func convertToJsonString()->String?{
        let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        jsonEncoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
        var encodedString:String?
        do {
            let encodePerson = try jsonEncoder.encode(self)
            let endcodeStringPerson = String(data: encodePerson, encoding: .utf8)!
            //print(endcodeStringPerson)
            encodedString = endcodeStringPerson
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return nil
        }
        return encodedString
    }
}

struct BookModel: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id:Int
    var bukTitle: String?
    var isLive: Bool?
    var userCanCopy: Bool?
    var bookContent: [BookContent]?
    var coverImage:String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case bukTitle = "title"
        case isLive = "is_live"
        case userCanCopy = "user_can_copy"
        case bookContent = "content"
        case coverImage = "bookCoverImage"
    }
}

struct BookContent: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title, type: String
    var child: [Child]
}

struct Child: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title, type: String
    var child: [Child]?
}

struct Buk: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()
    var bukTitle: String = ""
    var isLive: Bool = false
    var userCanCopy: Bool = false
    var bookContent: [BookContent] = []

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case bukTitle = "book_title"
        case isLive = "is_live"
        case userCanCopy = "user_can_copy"
        case bookContent = "book_content"
    }
}

@available(iOS 15, *)
func attributedString(from str: String, font: Font) -> AttributedString {
    if let theData = str.data(using: .utf16) {
        do {
            let theString = try NSAttributedString(data: theData, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
            var attaString = AttributedString(theString)
            attaString.font = font  // <-- here
            return attaString
        } catch {
            print("\(error)")
        }
    }
    return AttributedString(str)
}


enum BooksDirectory {
    /// Default, system Documents directory, for persisting media files for upload.
    case downloads

    /// Returns the directory URL for the directory type.
    ///
    fileprivate var url: URL {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        // Get a parent directory, based on the type.
        let parentDirectory: URL
        switch self {
        case .downloads:
            parentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        }
        return parentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(VBBooksManager.booksDirectoryName, isDirectory: true)
    }
}

class VBBooksManager:NSObject {
    fileprivate static let booksDirectoryName = "books"

    let directory: BooksDirectory
    
    @objc (defaultManager)
    static let `default`: VBBooksManager = {
        return VBBooksManager()
    }()
    
    // MARK: - Init
    /// Init with default directory of .uploads.
    ///
    /// - Note: This is particularly because the original Media directory was in the NSFileManager's documents directory.
    ///   We shouldn't change this default directory lightly as older versions of the app may rely on Media files being in
    ///   the documents directory for upload.
    ///
    init(directory: BooksDirectory = .downloads) {
        self.directory = directory
    }
    
    // MARK: - Instance methods
    /// Returns filesystem URL for the local Media directory.
    ///
    @objc func directoryURL() throws -> URL {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let mediaDirectory = directory.url
        // Check whether or not the file path exists for the Media directory.
        // If the filepath does not exist, or if the filepath does exist but it is not a directory, try creating the directory.
        // Note: This way, if unexpectedly a file exists but it is not a dir, an error will throw when trying to create the dir.
        var isDirectory: ObjCBool = false
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: mediaDirectory.path, isDirectory: &isDirectory) == false || isDirectory.boolValue == false {
            try fileManager.createDirectory(at: mediaDirectory, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        }
        return mediaDirectory
    }
    
    func saveBook(bookName:String,bookData:String)->Error?{
        //TODO: Save book into Document directory
        
        do {
            var finalBookName = bookName
            if !finalBookName.contains(".json"){
                finalBookName = "\(bookName).json"
            }
            
            let bookPath = try? self.directoryURL().appendingPathComponent(finalBookName)
            print(bookPath?.relativePath)
           
            
            do {
                let fileManager = FileManager.default
                if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: bookPath!.relativePath){
                    try fileManager.removeItem(at: bookPath!)
                }
                let data = Data(bookData.utf8)
                try? data.write(to: bookPath!, options: .atomic)
                //Just for Testing purpose call load book
//                let bookModel = try loadBookFromDocumentDirectory(bookName: finalBookName)
//                print(bookModel?.coverImage)
            }
            catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
                return error
            }
            
        }
        catch let error as NSError{
            print(error)
            return error
        }
       
        
        return nil
        
        //fileManager.wri wr(bookPath.relativePath, contents: Data(bookData), attributes: nil)
    }
    
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39415249/best-practice-for-swift-methods-that-can-return-or-error
    func loadBookFromDocumentDirectory(bookName:String) throws -> BookModel? {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        do {
            var finalBookName = bookName
            if !finalBookName.contains(".json"){
                finalBookName = "\(bookName).json"
            }
            let bookPath = try? self.directoryURL().appendingPathComponent(finalBookName)
            print(bookPath?.relativePath)
           
            
            do {
                if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: bookPath!.relativePath){
                    let jsonBookString = fileManager.contents(atPath: bookPath!.relativePath)
                    do {
                        let data = try Data(jsonBookString!)
                        guard let parsedBookObject:BookModel? = try JSONDecoder().decode(BookModel.self, from: data) else {
                            throw BookParseError.bookParsingFailed
                        }
                        return parsedBookObject ?? nil
                        //print(parsedBookObject)
                    }
                    catch let error as NSError{
                        print("error: \(error)")
                        throw error
                    }
                    
                }else{
                
                }
            }
            catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
                throw error
            }
            
        }
        catch let error as NSError{
            print(error)
            throw error
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    func loadAllSavedBooks()->[BookModel]?{
        var allBooks:[BookModel] = []
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        guard let booksPath = try? self.directoryURL() else {
            return []
        }
        print(booksPath)
        
        do {
            // Get the directory contents urls (including subfolders urls)
            let directoryContents = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: booksPath, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
            print(directoryContents)

            // if you want to filter the directory contents you can do like this:
            let books = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "json" }
            let bookNames = books.map{ $0.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent }
            print("bookNames list:", bookNames)
            //TODO: Load all the books and send array back

            for bookName in bookNames {
                do {
                    let book = try loadBookFromDocumentDirectory(bookName:bookName)
                    allBooks.append(book!)
                } catch BookParseError.bookParsingFailed {
                    continue
                }
                
                
            }
            return allBooks
            
            

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
        
    
        return allBooks
    }
    
    
    
}
```

[image]

**What i'm trying to achieve::**

Below is the image , how i'm trying to show image next to disclosure-group instead of on the top of each disclosure-group[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** *Included comments to better explain the code and show pictures*

You are probably nesting the `ForEach`, `NavigationLink` and Stacks in a strange way.

Try this and add your specific code along the View, including your model properties and AsyncImage. Format as you wish. The result should be what you are looking for.

```
struct Example: View {
    @State private var bookList: [Book]
    
    init() {
        let book1 = Book(image: "book", content: ["Line 1", "Line 2"])
        let book2 = Book(image: "book.closed.fill", content: ["Line A", "Line B", "Line C"])
        bookList = [book1, book2]
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        // "NavigationView" is necessary to allow moving from the list to the details
        NavigationView {
            VStack {

                // Title before the list
                Text("Total books: \(bookList.count)")
                
                // "List" will provide the items one after the other
                List(bookList) { book in
                    
                    // Here is what you see for each single item in the list
                    HStack {
                        
                        // "NavigationLink: is how you see the details by tapping on the item
                        NavigationLink {
                            
                            // This is the detail view
                            ScrollView {
                                Text("First line")
                                Text("Second line")
                                Text("Third line")
                                Text("Fourth line")
                            }
                        } label: {
                            
                            // This is the item view (how you see each item in the list)
                            HStack {
                                // Showing an Image
                                Image(systemName: book.image)
                                
                                // On the side of the image, show another list (without navigation)
                                VStack {
                                    ForEach(book.content, id: \.self) { bookContent in
                                        Text(bookContent)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                    
                    // This is just for decoration
                    .overlay {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .stroke(lineWidth: 2)
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                    }
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                }
                .listStyle(.plain)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how you see the list:

[image]

This is how you see the details when you tap on one of the items of the list:

[image]

Comment: I'm having difficulty relating the code. Could you please detail it out. I have updated new code with BookModel and Structure which can help you use relevant name conventions and update the code , thanks.

Comment: we are calling various images from directory as the images  are differed for different books AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "\(book.coverImage!)")) .scaledToFit()  .fixedSize(horizontal:true, vertical: true) .frame(minWidth: 10, maxWidth: 20)

Comment: how do i put async image instead of image so i can use image url like::(AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "\(book.coverImage!)")))?

Comment: @JigarDave: [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/asyncimage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/asyncimage) and [google.com](https://www.google.com)